# How can show the input field on toggle?

Tags: reactjs

I want to show the input field on toggling. The toggling is working but it is not showing the input field. How can I achieve this? I've tried but that is not showing the input field.

### Here's the code:

```
 handleToggle=()=>{
        console.log('In handletoggle')
        this.setState({
            milestone_based_payment:!this.state.milestone_based_payment
        })
    }

    percentRate=()=>{
        <>
        <div className="percent-rate-container">
            <Grid container>
                <Grid item md={12} lg={12} xs={12}>
                        <div className="percent-rate">PERCENT RATE</div>
                            <div>
                                <InputBase
                                className={`milestone-percent-rate`}
                                autoComplete={"off"}
                                placeholder={"PERCENT RATE"}
                                maxLength="100"
                                value={this.state.percent_rate}
                                onChange={(e)=>{this.handleChange(e, "percent_rate")}}
                            />
                            {
                                this.state.percent_rate_error && (
                                    <div className="input-error-style">{this.state.percent_rate_error}</div>
                                )
                            }
                            </div>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </div>
        </>
    }

    togglePayment=()=>{
        const {milestone_based_payment} = this.state;
        console.log('togglepayment')
        return(
            <div>
                <img src={milestone_based_payment ? PRIVATE_SwITCH : PUBLIC_SwITCH} alt="private-public" 
                    onClick={()=>this.handleToggle()}
                    style={{cursor: "pointer"}}/> 
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: I don't see where you're attempting to toggle visibility of the input. What does "the toggling is working" mean?

Comment: Where is your trying? your question and the codes are not clear at all!

Comment: Please give us a full example with your code.

Comment: if your input field is `InputBase` and you want to use `milestone_based_payment` as a `true or false` condition, then try this: `{(this.state.milestone_based_payment)?(<InputBase .../>):null}`

Comment: just put a condition where ever you want to use it in class`{(this.state.milestone_based_payment)?this.percentRate():null}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show/hide input field on true / false condition like this:

```
showHideInput() {
    if(this.state.milestone_based_payment === true) {
        return <input />
     }
}
// and call the method in other method 
// or inline condition
(this.state.milestone_based_payment === true) ? <input /> : <React.Fragment />
```

Comment: It does not working on jsx. you can not use the common syntax of if statement!

Comment: you can achieve it in jsx using true false shorthand

(this.state.milestone_based_payment === true) ? <input /> : <React.Fragment /<